# pandas Generate Data Frames by looping through names in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

Hello I am trying to create a loop to automate the code below

```
jacob = WT[(WT.Techs == 'JL') | (WT.Tech1 =='JL') | (WT.Tech2 =='JL') | (WT.Tech3 =='JL')]
marcus = WT[(WT.Techs == 'MO') | (WT.Tech1 =='MO') | (WT.Tech2 =='MO') | (WT.Tech3 =='MO')]
```

I have attempted the following code but it only generates a data frame for "name" rather than "jacob" or "marcus" and only for the last name in the list.

```
name = ('jacob', 'marcus')
tec = ('JL', 'MO')

for i in tec:
   name  = WT[(WT.Techs == i) | (WT.Tech1 == i) | (WT.Tech2 == i) | (WT.Tech3 == i)]
```

How can I generate a data frame named after the names in name and for the specific initials in `tec`?

Thanks!

Comment: `jacob, marcus = [WT[WT[['Techs', 'Tech1','Tech2','Tech3']].eq(tec).all(1)] for tec in ('JL', 'MO')]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang This won't work if the names are unknown

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary comprehension like the below code:

```
d = {x: WT[WT[['Techs', 'Tech1','Tech2','Tech3']].eq(y).all(1)] for x, y in zip(name, tec)]
```

To call it:

```
print(d['jacob'])
pritn(d['marcus'])
```

Comment: I tried this and now can get a data frame for each. However, each data frame is turning up empty. The resulting output is "Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Project, Week, Techs, Tech1, Tech2, Tech3, MilesCovered, DaysSpent, TotalHours, TotTechs, MilesPerTech]
Index: []"